# Bad character (ASCII 0) encountered while loading data into BigQuery

Tags: python, utf-8, google-bigquery, airflow

I'm trying to extract data from csv's inside a GCS directory and load them into BigQuery via an Airflow task. I get this error.

> 'message': 'Error while reading data, error message: Error detected
> while parsing row starting at position: 21. Error: Bad character
> (ASCII 0) encountered.'}.

How do I find the character at position 21 to know if it's the character ASCII 0 (which is Null)?. I've done an encoding check in python using the below code and it's saying that it's ran succesfully when the encoding field is the utf-8 that BQ requires.

```
with open(file_new, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        print(line)
```

How do I find out what's wrong and then how do I get the data from the csv's into the BQ tables?

Many thanks

Comment: U+0000 is a valid Unicode codepoint, though often a problematic one. So if python can correctly decode everything, doesn't necessarily mean that every program will accept your content. It's weird to have U+0000 (represented simply by the byte 00 in UTF-8, ASCII and all ASCII-based 8-bit encodings) in the middle of some text, so there's probably some problem with your input. Can you provide a hexdump of the first ~100 bytes of your file?

Comment: @JoachimSauer excuse me I'm a relatively new coder. How do I do that?

Comment: On Linux I'd do something like `hd -C myInputFile.txt`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I'm on mac. Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not a mac user, so I have no idea what tools Macs provide out of the box, you might get lucky and `hd` is one of them (it's a common unix utility and Mac OS X is unix-y). If that's not available then I'm sure you'll be able to find something using your favorite search engine.

Comment: Do a dump-like output inside Python as `x = open(file_new, 'rb').read(); print(x[0:100])`.

Comment: @ma8701: it seems like your file starts with a byte order marker, which is not wrong or a problem, but might require some additional handling, depending on your language (I don't know if Python handles it automatically). That doesn't explain the 0-character though ...